# From nginx, wake another server and redirect request to it

Tags: nginx

I have a server (srv1) which receives all request to "test.srv1".
I would like srv1 to be able to wake another server (srv2) if necessary , then redirect the request to srv2.
I thought to configure nginx to do it, but if someone has a better idea.

```
server {

    server_name test.srv1;

    location / {
        if (!-e $is_srv2_on) {
            # execute wol command
            echo_sleep 2;  # wait 2 seconds
        }

        return 301 $scheme://test.srv2;
    }
}
```

I don't know how to execute bash commands. I lokked into njs module without success.

Comment: Why can't you leave the other server on?

Comment: @MichaelHampton, because I don't want to.

Comment: This is a site for professional IT, not for hobbyist questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Michael Hampton mentioned, it would be much much more reliable to keep the other server on. WOL is a finicky beast at best. With that said, if you are determined to perform this idea, here's a solution.

Vanilla NGINX cannot do what you wish to perform, however, if you use the Openresty fork, it's trivial:

```
location / {
  rewrite_by_lua_block {
    os.execute("wakeonlan MAC-Address-Here")
    ngx.sleep(2)
  } 
  return 301 $scheme://test.srv2;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. It seems to be exactly what I am looking for. I am going to try Openresty and let you know.